# Joystick Simulink s-function using mmsystem.h

Tags: c++, matlab, winapi, simulink, joystick

I am trying to develop an s-function block to get Joystick input in Simulink. While it seems pretty straight forward with mmsystem.h, now I got lots of nonsense samples between real values. I basically use S-Function Builder with no inputs and an output that has the values from joystick. I use continuous sample mode. I have the below code in my Outputs tab.

```
JOYINFOEX joyInfoEx;
joyGetPosEx(0, &joyInfoEx);

y0[0] = joyInfoEx.dwXpos;
y0[1]=  joyInfoEx.dwYpos;
y0[2] = joyInfoEx.dwZpos;
y0[3] = joyInfoEx.dwRpos;

y0[4]= joyInfoEx.dwPOV;
```

My Continuous Derivatives and Discrete Update tabs are empty. But what I get when I run this s-fiction is something like below.

[image]

I ask for any ideas or experience to tackle this problem.

Comment: Have you looked at what the return value is?

Comment: Also, you are supposed to fill in the size and flags of `joyInfoEx` before calling `joyGetPosEx`.

Comment: This one works in VS as win32 console app so I believe it must be OK.

Comment: So then we probably need to see your input to Simulink and the corresponding outputs. I thought what you were showing was the output from `joyInfoEx` directly.

Comment: Yes actually there is no input of s-fuction block and what you see on the figure is simout of y0.